# jQuery- Erroneous duplicate append to list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very much new to web development and I've come across an issue when trying to implement a multi dimensional array, when I append a new li to an ul with the code below it produces 2 li's.

The parameters of the function are dest-the ul to append to and list-the multi dim array set as:

```
var webList2 = [["link.html","name"],["link.html","name"]...
```

I'm pretty sure there may be other issues with my code but it seems I may be missing something I'm not familiar with yet.

Anyone able to shed some light?

```
function expand(dest,list){
    var i = 2;

        function expandLoop() {
            setInterval(function() {

                if(i < list.length) {
                    i++;
                    var $newLi = $('<li><li>');
                    var $newA = $('<a></a>').attr('href',list[i][0]).text(list[i][1]);
                    $newLi.append($newA).appendTo(dest).hide().fadeIn(20);
                }

            }, 20);
        }

    $(expandLoop);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean it produces two lis? How are you calling expand? Creating an example with http://jsfiddle.net/ always helps too.

Comment: http://www.michaelburton.co.uk/ That is my original site and what I was trying to remake are the menu links to expand the list in an attempt to streamline the code and 'hopefully' learn something new. http://jsfiddle.net/tRJZs/ even though it looks horribly broken on here, you can see when clicking the web list 'expander', the items are duplicated.

Comment: Running fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crcuc/ Now your problem makes sense.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for the help, epascarello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't closing the `li` when creating it.

```
    var $newLi = $('<li></li>');
```

Change your line to that :P simple error, took me a while to catch it actually!

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/nPsr2/)**